# Tidying up my ASP.NET project has broken my relative paths

Tags: asp.net

I have just created some directories and tidied up my growing ASP.NET project but it has caused some issues that I can't solve. I have a directory in the root of the project called `js` and another one called `Pages`.

In `Pages` I have a file called `MasterPage.master` which is a master page. The `Pages` directory has `Default.aspx` and some subdirectories of other pages.

I have two main issues. In `MasterPage.master` I have code like this to reference javascript files:

`<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

However none of my javascript can be found any more. I tried `<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and I tried `<script src="~/js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` but it still doesn't work.

The other issue is that I have a menu system written is CSS and that has some strange behaviour. When the page loads the menu works fine. If I navigate to `/Pages/Trades/TradeInfo.aspx` and then hover over that item the page path now says `/Pages/Trades/Trades/TradeInfo.aspx`

Why has the Trades directory been added twice?

Comment: i would try ../ to get the root then js/jquery(etc)

Comment: Hi Daniel, no that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ResolveUrl`?
It sure works for the script tags and your anchor tags.

```
 <script src='<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.11.custom.min.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I now get this error when I try to run the page: `System.Web.HttpException: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).` Here's my line of code exactly: `<script src='<%=ResolveUrl ("~/js/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.min.js") %>' type="text/javascript"></script>`